# Add multiple consecutive integers in a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some javascript code that makes a variable with both characters and integers.

I need the consecutive integers inside this string to add together, while not affecting other individual or subsequent consecutive integers.

Lets say my input is

```
GhT111r1y11rt
```

I'd need my output to be:

```
GhT3r1y2rt
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback and inside callback calculate the sum using [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
console.log(
  'GhT111r1y11rt'.replace(/\d{2,}/g, function(m) { // get all digit combination, contains more than one digit
    return m.split('').reduce(function(sum, v) { // split into individual digit
      return sum + Number(v) // parse and add to sum
    }, 0) // set initial value as 0 (sum)
  })
)
```

Where `\d{2,}` matches 2 or more repetition of digits which is more better the `\d+` since we don't want to replace single digit.

Comment: @webdeb : that would return the sum ( Question : ___"consecutive integers inside this string to add together"___)

Answer (score 0):

The method isNaN() returns true when a character is numerical, use substr to check each character individually

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this for a same digit repeated multiple times (as in your example string):

```
'GhT111r1y11rt'.replace(/(\d)\1+/g, function (m,g1) { return g1 * m.length;});
```

`(\d)` captures the first digit
`\1+` repeat the captured digit (from the group 1)